Active Directory computer group membership
I have a Group policy that is applied to a security group. The group members are computer accounts that need this policy.
When I want to remove this policy from a computer, I remove it from members of this group but the problem is that the policy is still applied.
When I run below command after gpupdate /force i get the result in the picture:

gpresult /h result1.html


The only solution i found to update the group membership is to restart the computer:

Why is the computer still applying the policy?
Are there other solutions than rebooting?
UPDATE
I tried the solutions in the following similar question but when i purge system tickets (0x3e7) and get a new one, the ticket size is the same and computer thinks to be in group yet.
Is there a way to refresh computer group membership without rebooting?

Have you tried gpupdate /target:computer /force?

This question is similar to: Is there a way to refresh computer group membership without rebooting?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks for the reply but the question of me a little differs such that i remove computer from group rather than adding it, also the answers on that questions does not work i tried them my self too. - @GregAskew

Klist is the only solution to modify the group membership if a computer without restarting. More importantly, anything that requires dynamic and timely updating of computer group membership is a flawed design.

Thanks for sharing your experience and making the question more clear, @GregAskew
